# Ternary operators in JavaScript without an "else"

Tags: javascript, optimization, syntax-error

I've always had to put `null` in the else conditions that don't have anything. Is there a way around it?

For example,

```
condition ? x = true : null;
```

Basically, is there a way to do the following?

```
condition ? x = true;
```

Now it shows up as a syntax error.

FYI, here is some real example code:

```
!defaults.slideshowWidth ? defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px' : null;
```

Comment: use of a ternary like `condition ? x = true : null;` should probably be written as `x = (condition ? true : null);`. As an aside, in javascript `null` evaluates to false so in THIS case you could `x = (condition);` and achieve the same result.

Comment: matt, your answer is best, but it's not an answer, it's a comment!

Comment: Matt, my ACTUAL code is: !defaults.slideshowWidth ? defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px' : null ; a shorter, better way to write that?

Comment: defaults.slideshowWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth || obj.find('img').width()+'px' ;

Comment: it would be better to avoid the identity assignment, so this should just be a condition: `if (!defaults.slideshowWidth) defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px'`

Comment: But the name `defaults` strongly suggests that you shouldn't be mutating it here, so I suggest `const actualWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth || obj.find('img').width()+'px'`. Also, be careful if `slideshowWidth` might be an explicit 0, as that's falsy.

Comment: please add the value of `x` before the condition check takes place.

Comment: @Cheeso `x = (condition ? true : null);` will assign `null` value to the `x` if the condition is not satisfied. That's not expected generally.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

First of all, a ternary expression is not a replacement for an if/else construct - it's an equivalent to an if/else construct that **returns** a value. That is, an if/else clause is code, a ternary expression is an **expression**, meaning that it returns a value.

This means several things:

- use ternary expressions only when you have a variable on the left side of the `=` that is to be assigned the return value
- only use ternary expressions when the returned value is to be one of two values (or use nested expressions if that is fitting)
- each part of the expression (after ? and after : ) should return a value without side effects (the expression `x = true` returns true as all expressions return the last value, but it also changes x without x having any effect on the returned value)

In short - the 'correct' use of a ternary expression is

```
var resultofexpression = conditionasboolean ? truepart: falsepart;
```

Instead of your example `condition ? x=true : null ;`, where you use a ternary expression to set the value of `x`, you can use this:

```
 condition && (x = true);
```

This is still an expression and might therefore not pass validation, so an even better approach would be

```
 void(condition && x = true);
```

The last one will pass validation.

But then again, if the expected value is a boolean, just use the result of the condition expression itself

```
var x = (condition); // var x = (foo == "bar");
```

---

#### UPDATE

In relation to your sample, this is probably more appropriate:

```
defaults.slideshowWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth || obj.find('img').width()+'px';
```

Comment: brilliant SO, not allowing edit to correct `i/else` typo as it's not enough characters.

Comment: void(condition && x = true) - this looks great but seem to throw "invalid assignment left-hand side" error

Comment: void(condition && (x = true) ) // keeps the assignment separate from the first value

Comment: However, this is not intuitive to read, especially for developers not used to this style.  You could just as easily and more readably write this as: if (condition) { x=true; }

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* precisely a conditional ternary operator should only be used when its resulting value is assigned to your variable? I refer to point one of your list. The intention is understandable, but I would like to know if there is a specific reason not to use the ternary operator when the returned value is unused, such as performance, safety or something else.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "might not pass validation"? I don't understand why one should wrap the expression in `void()`. thanks.

Answer (score 32):

No, it needs three operands. That's why they're called *ternary* operators.

However, for what you have as your example, you can do this:

```
if(condition) x = true;
```

Although it's safer to have braces if you need to add more than one statement in the future:

```
if(condition) { x = true; }
```

**Edit:** Now that you mention the actual code in which your question applies to:

```
if(!defaults.slideshowWidth)
    { defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px'; }
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Atleast not without curly brackets around it - it's very errorprone.

Comment: is that true?  I understood the main reason for requiring curlies is because they make jslint's life easier.

Comment: @Cheeso it's errorprone in the sense of refactoring. YOu come back to add more to do in the case of a true condition without realizing there's no curly braces there. The new code will always execute rather than the case of when true.

Comment: No i know, i just like writing conditionals without extras such as if(){}else{} when its equal to simply ?:;

Comment: like i said, i know how to do a normal If/else conditional :) im asking if it was possible with a ternary, but it looks like not, thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I've never known developers more scared of using a language than Javascript :-P I wouldn't like someone telling me that I shouldn't use curly braces.  I omit them a lot and never have any more trouble than I would accidentally missing a brace.

Comment: @mdma How is it sidestepped? I made it clear that you can't have a two-operand ternary operator.

Comment: I think he means you didn't give an option other than if/else, which is fine, but I think mdma was looking more for (which some others gave): defaults.slideshowWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth || obj.find('img').width()+'px' ;

Comment: Agree with @AndyE, the idea of being worried that one might come back to add more clauses only to find the lack of curly brackets causes an error: you get these developer anxieties far more, the further away from machine code your language is. Best way to reduce such anxiety is to start coding in assembly, then come back to Javascript.

Answer (score 18):

More often, people use logical operators to shorten the statement syntax:

```
!defaults.slideshowWidth &&
  (defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width() + 'px');
```

But in your particular case the syntax can be even simpler:

```
defaults.slideshowWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth || obj.find('img').width() + 'px';
```

This code will return the `defaults.slideshowWidth` value if the `defaults.slideshowWidth` is evaluated to true and `obj.find('img').width() + 'px'` value otherwise.

See *[Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)* of logical operators for details.

Answer (score 14):

```
var x = condition || null;
```

Comment: `(defaults.slideshowWidth) || (defaults.slideshowWidth =  obj.find('img').width()+'px')` or `defaults.slideshowWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth || (obj.find('img').width()+'px')`

Comment: > Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. [Logical Operators (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description)

Answer (score 12):

We also have now the ["Nullish coalescing operator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (??). It works similar to the "OR" operator, but only returns the left expression if it's null or undefined, it doesn't return it for the other falsy values.

Example:

```
const color = undefined ?? 'black';   // color: 'black'
const color = '' ?? 'black';   // color: ''
const color = '#ABABAB' ?? 'black';   // color: '#ABABAB'
```

Answer (score 10):

You could write

```
x = condition ? true : x;
```

So that x is unmodified when the condition is false.

This then is equivalent to

```
if (condition) x = true
```

EDIT:

```
!defaults.slideshowWidth 
      ? defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px' 
      : null
```

There are a couple of alternatives - I'm not saying these are better/worse - merely alternatives

Passing in null as the third parameter works because the existing value is null. If you refactor and change the condition, then there is a danger that this is no longer true. Passing in the exising value as the 2nd choice in the ternary guards against this:

```
!defaults.slideshowWidth = 
      ? defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px' 
      : defaults.slideshowwidth
```

Safer, but perhaps not as nice to look at, and more typing. In practice, I'd probably write

```
defaults.slideshowWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth 
               || obj.find('img').width()+'px'
```

Comment: Some live code is (anyways to get rid of the null in this?): !defaults.slideshowWidth ? defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px' : null ;

Answer (score 3):

What about simply

```
    if (condition) { code if condition = true };
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a ternary operator without *else* inside of an array or object declaration, you can use the [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) spread operator, `...()`:

```
const cond = false;
const arr = [
  ...(cond ? ['a'] : []),
  'b',
];
    // ['b']
```

And for objects:

```
const cond = false;
const obj = {
  ...(cond ? {a: 1} : {}),
  b: 2,
};
    // {b: 2}
```

[Original source](https://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html)

Comment: there's still an else part in the conditional expression

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a guard expression instead (see Michael Thiessen's [excellent article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/conditional-class-binding-vue) for more).

Let `x` be a logical expression, that you want to test, and `z` be the value you want to return, when `x` is true. You can then write:

```
y == x && z
```

If `x` is true, `y` evaluates to `z`. And if `x` is false, so is `y`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case i see the ternary operator as redundant. You could assign the variable directly to the expression, using ||, &&  operators.

```
!defaults.slideshowWidth ? defaults.slideshowWidth = obj.find('img').width()+'px' : null ;
```

will become :

```
defaults.slideshowWidth = defaults.slideshowWidth || obj.find('img').width()+'px';
```

It's more clear, it's more "javascript" style.

Answer (score 1):

Why not writing a function to avoid the else condition?

Here is an example:

```js
const when = (statement, text) => (statement) ? text : null;

const math = when(1 + 2 === 3, 'Math is correct');
const obj = when(typeof "Hello Word" === 'number', "Object is a string");

console.log(math);
console.log(obj);
```

You could also implement that function for any objects. Here is an example for the type `string`:

```js
const when = (statement, text) => (statement) ? text : null;

String.prototype.if = when;

const msg = 'Hello World!';
const givenMsg = msg.if(msg.length > 0, 'There is a message! Yayyy!');
console.log(givenMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is:

```
if (y == x) z;
```

Answer (score -1):

Technically, it can return anything.
But, I would say for a one liner the Ternary is easier to type and at least 1 character shorter, so therefore faster.

```js
passTest?hasDriversLicense=true:0
if(passTest)hasDriversLicense=true
```

Comment: "*so therefore faster*" - that doesn't follow

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32154673)