# Javascript ternary operator shortcut

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I've tried to search over SE without great success, however link me to the right topic if I'm wrong.
What I'd like to achieve is use a shortcut of JS's ternary operator, let me explain myself :
In PHP, you can do something like

```
<?php 
    $var1 = "1"; //example
    $var2 = ($var1) ?: "2";
    echo $var2 //echoes "1";
?>
```

as you can see/may already know, `?:` returns `$var1` when if evaluates to "true" (in this case `!empty($var1)`, or "2" otherwise.
Now my question is, is there a way do achieve the same thing in Javascript?

Comment: A shortcut for an operator that is already a shorthand for an if / else statement?

Comment: Yes, and [the syntax is identical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)! You could have just tried it.

Comment: Actually it would have been hard to ignore SE's suggestions when asking

Comment: @mplungjan - The proper duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932754/ternary-operators-in-javascript-without-an-else and not the linked question.

Comment: Please read the question before swinging Mjölnir, so that you might mark as the *right* duplicate.

Comment: People need to read the question; `?:` is not a valid javascript operator token  as it is in PHP

Comment: I can't really see why I got downvoted here ... as I didn't know how to use it, I couldn't have known about the || operator ... whatever.

Comment: as I explained in the note that was deleted by an edit, I had no way of searching for || because I didn't know what to look for, if you know what I mean.