# Map() function with inner function or nested Ternary Operator best practices Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, map-function

I have two methods of writing the same function using Map(), from my reading I can not tell if there is a best practices method

Related to this are nested `ternary` operations considered bad practice?

Method2

```
function Method2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Elements');  
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  var values = rng.getValues();
  
  values = values.map(x => x.map(y => giveNumber(y)));
  
  sht.getRange(1,1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}


function giveNumber(str) {  
  if(str=="Networking - 1") {str=1}
  else if(str=="Cooperating - 2") {str=2}
  else if (str=="Collaborating - 3"){str=3}
  else if(str=="Partnering - 4") {str=4}
  else {str=str}
  return str
}
```

Method3

```
function Method3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Elements');  
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  var values = rng.getValues();
  
  values = values.map(x => x.map(y => y==("Networking - 1") ? 1: 
                                      y==("Cooperating - 2") ? 2: 
                                      y==("Collaborating - 3") ? 3: 
                                      y==("Partnering - 4") ? 4: 
                                      y));
  
  
  sht.getRange(1,1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple conditions to check, ternary operators can not be used efficiently.

It is recommended to use an `if/else if` statement:

```
values = values.map(x => x.map(y =>
                    {
                    if (y== "Networking - 1"){
                    return 1;
                    }
                    else if(y=="Cooperating - 2"){
                    return 2;
                    }
                    else if(y=="Collaborating - 3"){
                    return 3;
                    }
                    else {
                    return 4;                     
                    }                
                    }
 ));
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to know. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the accepted answer. Ternary operators can be used effectively for multiple `if/else` statements. If used with proper  code intents/style, it doesn't harm readability and is shorter.

```
const mapFunc = y =>
  y == 'Networking - 1'
    ? 1
    : y == 'Cooperating - 2'
    ? 2
    : y == 'Collaborating - 3'
    ? 3
    : y == 'Partnering - 4'
    ? 4
    : y;
```

Variability does exist in performance as well. Although this is not tested in newer [v8](/questions/tagged/v8) engine, In older [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino) engine, [ternary operators were the fastest](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/07/11/benchmark-conditional-branch-using-google-apps-script/).

Given multiple conditions on the same variable, it is also apt to use [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statements instead.

---

In your specific case however, If you're just trying to get the last number in the string, You could just get the last  character or use regex:

```
y => Number(y[y.length-1]) || y
```

Another alternative is to use Arrays with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) :

```
const strs = [
  'Networking - 1',
  'Cooperating - 2',
  'Collaborating - 3',
  'Partnering - 4',
];
const mapFunc = y => strs.indexOf(y) + 1 || y;
```

Also see:

[Ternary operators in JavaScript without an "else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932754/ternary-operators-in-)